# SQL join 2 tables without relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I am trying to join 2 tables. However, the two tables don't have a relationship or an unique identifier to join on.

The 2 tables log information about the same: activities and the duration of activities on different websites. Table A contains detailed timelogs of the activity, EXCEPT it doesn't log the website name. Table B (like Table A) also contains activity duration information (not as detailed as A) but it logs the website name. Both tables log the same, BUT contain different information.

In short: Table A contains detailed activity duration BUT no website name, Table B contains the website name, BUT not detailed activity duration. 
So both table log information about the same, except

Here is my problem:

The 2 tables

TABLE A

```
ID|        Start    |       End       |  Key  | Value  
====================================================== 
1 | 2016-04-07 08:30| 2016-04-07 08:30| Busy  | 12
1 | 2016-04-07 08:36| 2016-04-07 08:37| Logout| 345
1 | 2016-04-07 09:16| 2016-04-07 09:16| Login | 67
2 | 2016-04-07 08:10| 2016-04-07 08:11| Login | 45
2 | 2016-04-07 08:10| 2016-04-07 08:11| Write | 8
```

TABLE B:

```
ID|   Website |      Date       |  
==================================
1 | A         | 2016-04-07 08:32|
1 | A         | 2016-04-07 08:39|
1 | B         | 2016-04-07 09:17|
2 | A         | 2016-04-07 08:12| 
2 | A         | 2016-04-07 08:14|
```

Result that I am looking for:

```
ID|        Start    |       End       |  Key  | Value | Website |
================================================================== 
1 | 2016-04-07 08:30| 2016-04-07 08:30| Busy  | 12    |  A      |
1 | 2016-04-07 08:36| 2016-04-07 08:37| Logout| 345   |  A      |  
1 | 2016-04-07 09:16| 2016-04-07 09:16| Login | 67    |  B      |
2 | 2016-04-07 08:10| 2016-04-07 08:11| Login | 45    |  A      |
2 | 2016-04-07 08:10| 2016-04-07 08:11| Write | 8     |  A      |
```

Users can do activities on more then 1 website on the same time. The result I want is the activityname + duration (value) (TABLE A) for each website (TABLE B) the user has worked on.

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` I tried works, if the user has only logged in on ONE website only:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.STart, a.End, a.Key, a.Value, b.Website
FROM TABLE A as a   
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE B as b 
on a.ID = b.ID
WHERE b.Date BETWEEN '2016-04-07' and '2016-04-08'
AND a.Start BETWEEN '2016-04-07' and '2016-04-08'
AND b.agentid = '1'
AND website is not NULL
GROUP BY a.ID, a.Start, a.End, a.Key, a.Value, b.Website
```

If the user logged on onto 2 websites, the values of the join duplicate, a value for each website (but I only want the website the user has worked on in that timeframe). I can't edit these tables (A & B), but I can make new tables.
My question: is this possible and if so, how do I do this?

Comment: There is nothing between those tables that indicates which row in TableA corresponds to a given row in TableB. Maybe you can kludge this into a join using ROW_NUMBER but that seems awfully brittle. Look at the second row in TableA, the time is 8:36 and 8:37. How do you know that is related to the row in TableB with 8:39??? It is very unclear what you are trying to do here. This might be a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I edited my question with some more information about what the 2 tables log and contain. I hope this clarifies things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outer apply` might be the easiest solution:

```
select a.*, b.website
from a outer apply
     (select top 1 b.*
      from b
      where b.id = a.id and
            b.date >= a.start
      order by b.date desc
     ) b;
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me alot!